# Why does Firefox and Chrome keep crashing?

Tags: 12.04, firefox, google-chrome

I did a fresh install of Ubuntu, installing 12.04. 
For a week or so everything was fine then the browsers kept crashing.

**Chrome** constantly keeps giving me the "aw snap" window, there is no particular page it happens on but it often crashes when i go on twitter and Google news.

**Firefox** gave me the following report after it crashed a few moments ago:

```
Add-ons: langpack-en-GB@firefox.mozilla.org:12.0,langpack-en-ZA@firefox.mozilla.org:12.0,globalmenu@ubuntu.com:3.2.3,ubufox@ubuntu.com:2.0.3,{972ce4c6-7e08-4474-a285-3208198ce6fd}:12.0
BuildID: 20120423122624
CrashTime: 1341360241
EMCheckCompatibility: true
FramePoisonBase: 00000000f0dea000
FramePoisonSize: 4096
InstallTime: 1336864437
Notes: OpenGL: NVIDIA Corporation -- GeForce 8400 GS/PCIe/SSE2 -- 3.3.0 NVIDIA 295.40 -- texture_from_pixmap

ProductID: {ec8030f7-c20a-464f-9b0e-13a3a9e97384}
ProductName: Firefox
ReleaseChannel: release
SecondsSinceLastCrash: 565
StartupTime: 1341359678
Theme: classic/1.0
Throttleable: 1
URL: http://www.google.co.uk/
Vendor: Mozilla
Version: 12.0

This report also contains technical information about the state of the application when it crashed.
```

Thanks for your help!

Comment: What version of flash do you have installed for FF?  I don't know about Chrome, but there have been reports of a flash bug making FF more crashy.  See http://arstechnica.com/civis/viewtopic.php?f=15&t=1176823

Comment: This question appears to be abandoned and unanswered, if you are experiencing a similar issue please [ask a new question](http://askubuntu.com/questions/ask) with details pertaining to your problem. If you feel this question is *not* abandoned, please flag the question explaining that.